# Blocked Access to geolocation was blocked over secure connection with mixed content

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, google-maps, ssl, https

I'm using a plugin in WordPress that uses the Google Maps API but keep getting this error:

> [blocked] Access to geolocation was blocked over secure connection with mixed content to...

My site is on SSL, and I've checked that the google API script is not trying to be pulled in via http (it is https as it should be).

I'm not sure what could be causing this issue. Maybe there is something I need to do in my htaccess file? Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check below list,

1. Your site have http link instead of https links, so only you facing the mixed content warning( you can fine this warning in your browser console). Find those links in your website and change those as a https links.
2. Add google API key in configuration. 
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key